# Populate table cell with results from resultsarray from SWAPI

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm working on getting SWAPI (star wars API) from this site -->https://swapi.co/ to populate on my tableview cell, but I'm a little confused on how to go about grabbing the characters and displaying them all w/ an empty array. 
the variable "people" works and it grabs those exact characters and displays in the console their data. 
How would I go about doing this in the viewDidLoad() ? This is what I have so far. I am also doing this in swift 2.3. A

```
import UIKit

class PeopleViewController: UITableViewController {

//    var people = ["Luke Skywalker", "Leia Organa", "Han Solo", "C-3PO", "R2-D2"]

var people = [Person]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://swapi.co/api/people/")
    // Create an NSURLSession to handle the request tasks
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    // Create a "data task" which will request some data from a URL and then run a completion handler after it is done
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {
        data, response, error in
        print("in here")
        print(data)

        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonResult)
                if let results = jsonResult["results"] {
                    let resultsArray = results as! NSArray
                    print(resultsArray.count)
                    print(resultsArray.firstObject)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // return the count of people
    return people.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Create a generic cell
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    // set the default cell label to the corresponding element in the people array
    cell.textLabel?.text = people[indexPath.row]
    // return the cell so that it can be rendered
    return cell
}

}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you need to take the data from your results array, create `Person` objects from it in your completion handler, and put them in your `people` array.  Then tell your table to reload its data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea. You just need to populate your people array and then tell the table view to reload itself (from the main thread)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://swapi.co/api/people/")
    // Create an NSURLSession to handle the request tasks
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    // Create a "data task" which will request some data from a URL and then run a completion handler after it is done
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {
        data, response, error in
        print("in here")
        print(data)

        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonResult)
                if let results = jsonResult["results"] {
                    let resultsArray = results as! NSArray
                    print(resultsArray.count)
                    print(resultsArray.firstObject)
                    //------------------------------------------------------
                    //Install the array in people and tell the table view to 
                    //reload
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                      //Replace the code below with code create Person
                      //objects from your data.
                      people = resultsArray.map(){Person(name:$0)}
                      tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                    //------------------------------------------------------
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```